# Localizing Numbers in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization, nsnumberformatter, nslocale

Simply, I have a positive integer [9, 393, 3, 993], and I would like to localize it to a certain language [٩, ٣٩٣ ,٣ ,٩٣٩].

If I use `NSNumberFormatter`, it will localize the number according to the user's locale. However, I want to override that and choose any locale to translate the number to.

I tried the following, did **not** work:

```
// user locale is @"en"
NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar"]];


[formatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:padding];
return [formatter stringFromNumber:@(num)];
```

The returned string is in English.

---

Please note that I have a very similar code snippet for `NSDateFormatter`, but it works as expected. The `NSDateFormatter` object respects the set locale.

Comment: Of course, I am looking for a solution for `NSNumberFormatter`, but if someone happens to know a nifty regular expression or mapping function, I'd love to use it. Just map 1 <-> ١ and so on.. You can use http://www.yamli.com/ar/

Comment: I have run your code in the iOS simulator and on an iPhone device: For `num = 123` it returned the string "١٢٣". (The `currentLocale` is "en_US").

Comment: Same experience as @MartinR here; the code above correctly returned numbers in the Arabic locale regardless of what I had my device set to.

Comment: @MartinR I never expected that the code would execute differently across two projects. I created a new project, and pasted the code, it worked! ... I have to revisit my old project.

Comment: http://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html Check this link out...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems I came across a very special case where the locale of the app would just freak out.

I am changing the default locale of the app by using something like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[@"ar"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Then, I was trying to get the preferred language and create a locale object from it using:

```
NSString* langPrefix = [NSLocale preferredLanguages][0];
```

Finally, create a new `NSLocale` object from the returned object. When testing the code, I would change the language from within the app, then close the app through Xcode. I am assuming that the `NSUserDefaults` would not synchronize, but even if I called the `synchronize` method, it would still screw up.

Bottom line is, testing localization should be done by deploying the app, and after the device has been disconnected from Xcode, so the app would run through all the life-cycle stages properly.